# wordpress hook to redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want redirect all incoming traffic to homepage.
I found solution but not sure if it he best one.

```
function redirect_sample() {

    if(!is_front_page())
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
        exit;
    }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_sample' );
```

Also i found that can hook to wp

```
function redirect_sample() {

    if(!is_front_page())
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
        exit;
    }

}

add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_sample' );
```

And my question is were is better to hook witch plugin.
Also is there any "MAP" when/order hooks loaded in sequence ?

Comment: It's better to do it at the server level, and avoid doing a hook altogether.

Comment: like this ??   RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase {HTTP_HOST}
    RewriteRule ^\(.*)$ \ [L,R=301]

Comment: If you intend to remove the redirect at some point in the future, use a 302 "temporary" redirect as a 301 is "permanent" and will be cached by browsers even if you remove it from your htaccess file.